# How can I stop the Photos app showing the "What's New Photos" screen every time I launch it?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, photos.app, bug

I'm on macOS 10.13.3, and every time I launch the *Photos* app, I get the following screen, showing "What's New Photos". I have to click the "Get Started" button to access my library, which works every time, but is a bit of a nuisance.

[image: screenshot]

This seems like a bug in the app, but perhaps there's some sort of work-around. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: This is a bug, it shouldn't be showing up every time. What version of Photos are you using?

Comment: @Christian Version 3.0 (3251.12.190)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the edition I'm using too, presumably the most updated. Hopefully someone else can propose a solution.

Comment: @Christian Yeah... it's weird. I wonder if it's something to do with the fact my library is not in the default location.

Comment: I have tahe same problem too. I'm searching any solve but l couldn't :(((

Comment: The problem disappeared in the last macOS upgrade.

Comment: That sounds like an answer?

Comment: @grg Sure, I'll post it!

Answer (score 1):

This problem eventually disappeared in some minor version upgrade of macOS Mojave I believe (possibly even the upgrade to Mojave itself). I then had the problem that occasionally Photos.app would "forget" that I had set my system photo library to one on an external drive, which was less bad, but still not ideal. Since upgrading to macOS, that problem has however been fixed too, I'm glad to say.